Как обойти капчу и передать ее в пост запрос?
Отправляю пост запрос на url supercell id: https://id.supercell.com/api/ingame/account/login
Раньше данный метод работал и отправлялся код на почту, но сейчас он возвращает в ответ только: {'ok': True}
Сам запрос:
def login(self, email: str, game: str) -> None:
    self.headers = {
        "User-Agent": f"scid/4543 (Android; laser-prod)",
        "Authorization": '',
    }
    login_data = {
        "lang": 'en',
        "email": email,
        "remember": "true",
        "game": game,
        "env": "prod",
    }
    response = requests.post(url=f'{self.base_url}/ingame/account/login', data=login_data, headers=self.headers)
    print(response.json()) #Response = {'ok': True}

Я спросил на одном форуме по этому поводу и мне ответили, что там сделали капчу, которую надо решить и передать в запрос. Как это можно сделать? я просто не понял(

нашли решение? у меня такая же проблема...
буду рад если свяжитесь со мной тг - @stargrapefruit может вместе найдем решение
